# Dropdown menu with radio buttons

Tags: drop-down-menu, html.dropdownlistfor

My client wants 2 radio buttons (check boxes would work to) for each item in the drop down menu.

This way the client can choice item 1 for a example and they can choice either and or the option or. How can I do this?

My client is paranoid about their data or program being seen by others. But I have added a mock-up of what they would like.

Comment: My client is paranoid about their data or program being seen by others.

Comment: ![enter image description here][1]

  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/0AZNy.png

Answer (score 0):

You can place the individual items inside a DIV thats hidden at first and then using javascript code, make the DIV appear when any other object (most likely a button) is clicked.